# Datatable get value of hidden column

Tags: jquery, datatable

jQuery:

```
$.fn.dataTable.ext.search.push(
    function(settings, data, dataIndex) {
        var position = table.fnGetPosition(dataIndex);
        var hiddenColumnValue = table.fnGetData(position)[0];
        console.log(hiddenColumnValue);
    }
);
```

Error:

```
Cannot read property 'fnGetPosition' of undefined
```

Anyone can Please help me why this error is appearing and How can I resolve this error?

Comment: what does table refer to, please show us all relevant code.

Comment: "*How can I resolve this error?*" by storing your dt instance in a global variable, i.e `var table = $('#example').dataTable();` Marking the question as duplicated since it is been answered several times before, and there is really not much to add to it